# Is it possible to put bower.json outside root folder?

Tags: bower

When defining a package, Is it possible to put the bower.json file inside a subdirectory of my git repository, and reference it in other projects?

I know that the [docs says to put it in the root](http://bower.io/#defining-a-package), but I already have my own directory structure on my git repository and want to put it inside a subdirectory.

I'm wondering if exists an option inside .bowerrc file to configure bower.json location. That would solve my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this question is pretty old but none of the answers address the OP's actual question.

It is possible to store your `bower.json` in a subdirectory of your project (or another project for that matter).

In your `.bowerrc`, use the `cwd` (current working directory) setting to specify where your json file is stored.

More info can be found in the [bower configuration docs](http://bower.io/docs/config/#cwd).

Answer (score 0):

Bower will create the **./bower_components** folder next to the **bower.json** file.

So, as long as you ensure that the paths of the js/css files are OK, you can put the components wherever you want.

In my case, I have to use different versions/dependencies for an HTML5 mobile app and a Bootstrap/Angular backend. So I have something like that:

```
/bower.json
/bower_components/
/app/bower.json
/app/bower_components/
```

Just be sure to include your **bower.json** files in the GIT tree and add the **bower_components** folders to the **.gitignore** file

Hope it helps